# Expected value to get number 1 when roll the dice three times

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

I fighting with one practise. Questions is what is expected number of 1s when tossing a die (6 faces) three times?

For one die it is $(1/6)\times(1+2+3+4+5+6)=3.5$.

Comment: Do you mean probability rather than expected value?

Comment: @Henry No, this practise what i doing need expected value. All examples on internet is about probability.

Comment: Probability is easy to calculate. 1/6*1/6*1/6=1/216. But that is not what i looking for. I want expected value.

Comment: Expected value of what? when you are tossing dice for three times and you are concerned with getting three times 1, whose expected value are you calculating

Comment: Question in this practice is: "Toss a six faced die three times. What is expected value of number of ones?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you give the expected value of one die, are you asking about the expected *total* of three dice? If so, this is just three times the expected total for one die, by linearity of expectation, so $10.5$.

Similarly, the expected number of 1s is three times what it would be for one die, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried 10.5 for the answer and it's not that. It is hard to understand that question even. I tried these answers: 10.5, 1/216 and both wrong. 

1/216 is probability to get number one three times in a row. 

3.5 is expected value of one toss. So three would is 10.5. But that is not right answer either.

Comment: @masteroscar perhaps the question is asking for the expected number of 1s, which is $0.5$?

Comment: Hi, just 5min ago tried 0,5 and it was right. Still confused of this question it was easier that i thought.

Answer (score 2):

The expected number of $1$s from one dice roll is $\frac16$

So, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of $1$s from three dice rolls is three times that, i.e. $\frac12=0.5$

Answer (score 1):

Let us introduce a random variable $$X=\text{number of 1s within 3 dice tossings}.$$

The possible values of $X$ are 0, 1, 2, 3.

$X$ follows [***binmial distribution***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)  with parameters $n = 3$ and $p = \frac{1}{6}$, i.e. $X\sim Bin\left(n=3, p = \frac{1}{6}\right)$.

Then, the expected value of $X$ is $$E\left[X\right] = n\cdot p = 3\cdot \frac{1}{6} = 0.5$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Indicator random variable for this, the solution is quite elegant.

Consider $I_i$ an indicator variable that is 1 if the *ith* dice rolls 1 or 0 otherwise.
In this case a r.v. X that represents the number of ones out of the 3 rolls can be written as:

$$X = I_1 + I_2 + I_3$$

And the expectation:
$$E(X) = E(I_1) + E(I_2) + E(I_3) = P(I_1) + P(I_2) + P(I_3) = 3 \times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$$